# How do I properly display a list of errors beneath my component?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, iterator

I'm using React 16.13.0 and Bootstrap 4.  I want to display a list of field errors when the proper variable is populated in my component.  I have this

```
  {props.errors && props.errors[props.name] && (
      <FormControl.Feedback>
             {props.errors[props.name].map((error, index) => ( 
                 <div key={field-error-${props.name}-${index}} className="fieldError">{error}</div>
             )}  
      </FormControl.Feedback>
  )}
```

However this fails to compile

```
  Line 20:45:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "}"

  18 |           <FormControl.Feedback>
  19 |                  {props.errors[props.name].map((error, index) => (
> 20 |                      <div key={field-error-${props.name}-${index}} className="fieldError">{error}</div>
     |                                             ^
  21 |                  )} 
  22 |           </FormControl.Feedback>
  23 |       )}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong -- is there another way to reference my props.name var?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing backticks:

```
key={`field-error-${props.name}-${index}`}
```

Comment: Also if `{error}` is object, it won`t work. Use string instead